# generate new version number start with 1 based on group of data

Tags: sql, oracle

need some help for the solution I'm looking with below sample data , want to assign new version number start with 1 for the group (book_name,version)

```
book_name      version   language 
math_1           1         english
math_1           2         english
physics_1        3         english
physics_6        4         spanish
physics_6        4         english
chemist_1        3         english
chemist_2        4         english
chemist_5        4         spanish
chemist_9        4         Hindi
eng_1            1         english
```

i want a query to rerun below result based on above table data expected result would be

```
book_name      version   language 
math_1           1         english
math_1           2         english
physics_1        1         english
physics_6        2         spanish
physics_6        2         english
chemist_1        1         english
chemist_2        2         english
chemist_5        2         spanish
chemist_9        2         Hindi
eng_1            1         english
```

Thanks in advance and appreciate you help

Comment: You will have to explain why the first occurence of  `physics_6`gets version = 2. Similar is valid for `chemist_2, 5 and 9`

Comment: Looks like `DENSE_RANK` on a partition by the book name before the underline and order by existing version number to me.

Comment: thanks for the response , want to generate new version number always start with 1 and increment by 1 .. for the group(book_name, version ) , so once first group  ( physics_1 ,3)  start with 1 , the next group (physics_6 , 4) need to start with version number 2

Comment: @ThorstenKettner  , thanks for your help dense_rank  works for me , thanks again

Comment: thanks @MarmiteBomber for your response Thorsten response (dense_rank) works for my requirement

Comment: I am glad it does. So I guessed right :-)  I was about to say that your explanation didn't match your explanation, for what you describe here in the comments would result in math_1/1 = 1, math_1/2 = 2, physics_1/3 = 3, physics_6/4 = 4, chemist_1/3 = 5, chemist_2/4 = 6, chemist_5/4 = 7, chemist_9/4 = 8. This looks like a bad data model, because your book titles chemist_2 and chemist_5 are different for instance, but you want to treat them as one book title. You should have separate columns for the title 'chemist' and the number hence.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by book_name, language order by version) as new_version
from t;
```

Or, if you want to change the version using an `update`:

```
update t
    set version = (select count(*)
                   from t t2
                   where t2.book_name = t.book_name and
                         t2.language = t.language and
                         t2.version <= t.version
                  );
```

Comment: HI Gordon , thanks for your response i tried you approach and it doesn't give me expected out put chemist_1 3 english 1
chemist_2 4 english 1
chemist_5 4 spanish 1
chemist_9 4 Hindi 1
eng_1 1 english 1
math_1 1 english 1
math_1 2 english 1
physics_1 3 english 1
physics_6 4 spanish 1
physics_6 4 english 2

Comment: thanks @Gordon Linoff  and thanks for your prompt response Thorsten response (dense_rank) works for my requirement